# Regex to replace 'null-null-1234' to 'xxx-xx-1234'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace string

```
'null-null-1234' to  '***-**-1234'


const p = 'null-null-1234';

const regex = /null/gi;

console.log(p.replace(regex, '***'));

Output => "***-***-1234" NOT AS EXPECTED
```

Comment: What is the logic here? You may just use `p.replace("null", "***").replace("null", "**")` if the first one must be replaced with `***` and the second one with `**`

Comment: It's vague, add more examples; input > expected output

Comment: What @WiktorStribiżew said. BTW: The 'g' option would replace multiple occurrences in a line. So if you didn't use g, you could replace the first one with '***' and then use a 2nd regex on the 2nd line. But regex is overkill for a simple search/replace like this one.

Comment: Are you formatting a SSN string? Last 4? Provide more details and sample data. Is the input format always `'null-null-' . /[0-9]{4}/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p.replace(/null-null/, '***-**')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want to do is to make a distinction between first and second values.
Hence, you probably need 2 regexes.

`p.replace(/^null/, '***').replace(/-null-/, '-**-')`

The first one will replace the null in first position (if any) by 3 stars, and the second replace will replace a null in the middle (if any) by 2 stars.